# search for words with sql greater than 3

Tags: php, mysql

I using explode in php to split up words, I need then to search for that word in my category list, if a match, then use that category id and create the listing. Only problem is I come across words only one letter ie: "E Cigarettes & Vape Mods"

I don't want to use the "E" that would come up with way too many categories, what is the best solution, if size of word 3 or 4 search that? just thinking aloud. Thanks inadvance

Comment: Make your search work on whole words only?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Please clarify with some code, some data, or both.

Comment: show your code. and proper example

Comment: If I correctly understand, you can just filter your words after explode,  by checking character lengths (using `strlen()`, `mb_strlen()` functions) for each word and if length > 1, then search in database

Comment: can you be more clear that what exactly you want??  and show some of your try code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **len** function: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp

I.e:
select len('word'), outputs 4.

Answer (score 0):

I used strlen then if greater than 3 search that word

```
$categoryName = str_replace(",","",$categoryName);
$wordsplit = explode(' ',$categoryName);            
foreach($wordsplit as $wordCat)
{   
    if($found) break;
    if(strlen($wordCat) > 3)
//DO SOMETHING
}
```